# How to use SAML2 protocol client side?

Tags: javascript, frontend, client, saml-2.0

I'm trying to use the SAML2 protocol client side. Someone suggested me I use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js, though this one is serverside.

Is there a cdn library that could help me with this?

I try using the saml2-js on the front using browserify, also using the request on client library and whatnot, but it just won't work.

So my question is, how can I use the SAML protocol client side.

Comment: Maybe adding a little snippet of you code will help us to understand.

Comment: From a security perspective, this is a "Very Bad Idea". The client-side should not validate its authentication to another authority. If it can do that, then what's preventing it from just declaring who it is, instead of going to ask the identity provider?